# How to extract a BIP39 mnemonic from an Ed25519 encrypted private key?

Tags: keys

How to generate a BIP39 mnemonic from an Ed25519 (Ed25519+libsodium, with 8 for salt, 48 for key plus 32 bytes) encrypted private key?
I have an Ed25519 encrypted private key (for which I know the password). I would like to create a [BIP39 mnemonic](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mnemonic_phrase) from it.

This is to import a private key generated elsewhere into a Nano Ledger S wallet. I get this is not recommended, but I am aware of the risks and want to make it an exercise.

Comment: This is so crypto-currency specific, I'm thinking that this does not belong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Ed25519 private key can come in any of [several typical forms](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54367/49826)—almost always either just a 32-byte or 64-byte string.  Which form you have or need depends on what software or protocol you are using it with.

For, *e.g.*, a BIP32-style hierarchical wallet, for instance, you almost certainly need the full 64-byte string encoding the PRF secret and the secret scalar.  I don't know about the Nano Ledger S: if you want a specific answer about it, you'll have to point to specific documentation about the specific protocol that the Nano Ledger S implements.

If you *already have* an Ed25519 private key, then you can't generate a BIP39 mnemonic from it because BIP39 is a system for *generating keys* by way of generating mnemonics from which the keys are derived.  **Inventing a BIP39 mnemonic for a private key not generated from one would be an amazing feat of cryptography demonstrating an unbelievably structured preimage attack on SHA-256.**

If you want to *generate* an Ed25519 private key by way of a mnemonic, then you could in principle use BIP39 for that.  Whether the software you're using supports it, I can't say.

If all you want is a memorable representation of an Ed25519 private key or any other (say) 32-byte string, you could take a (say) 256-entry word list, and map each octet to a word, yielding a 32-word mnemonic.  If 32 words is too long, you could use a 65536-entry word list and map a 32-byte string to a 16-word mnemonic.  That's not BIP39, but it is a potentially memorable way you could back up an Ed25519 private key.

Comment: Updated question to specify better the type of Ed25519

Comment: @Gaia I'm not really sure what you mean by ‘Ed25519+libsodium, with 8 for salt, 48 for key plus 32 bytes’, but in any case, the main point of the answer remains unchanged: BIP39 doesn't help you to make a mnemonic for an existing key; it only helps you to simultaneously generate a mnemonic and a key.

Comment: I actually don't need the seed phrase anymore (see updated question)

Comment: @Gaia OK…can you revert it to the original question, and ask a new question?  This is a completely different question now—I answered ‘Can I create a BIP39 mnemonic for an existing key?’ but your question is now ‘Can I extract a BIP32 private key from an existing Ed25519 key format?’.

Comment: done. thank you for your patience. new q is at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60697/